# Angular - Help me find the eslint rule or compiler option to prevent variable typo's in functions

Tags: angular, compilation, eslint

So I've recently switched from tslint to eslint and have activated a lot of rules for my typescript to be more solid.

I however haven't found how to prevent typo's of my class variables in a function.
Take this example:

Class input has a variable Seal.
I have a getter & setter like this:

```
public get Seal(): string {
    return this._Seal;
}

public set Seal(value: string) {
    if (typeof(value) === 'string'){
        this._Seak = value.toLowerCase();
    } else { this._Seak = null; }
}
```

As you can see, there is a typo in the setter function which is not flagged by the compiler nor eslint.
The app runs and it's much later I find out that Seal is not getting the assigned value.
What option do I need to use (compiler option or eslint) to flag this?

I tried the "no-use-before-define" rule, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my issue was caused by a previous setting either in `tslint` or compiler options that caused a new class variable to be created instead of flagging the typo in the Seal Setter.

I realized I had a variable (which I did not create) added to my class that made every typo valid

```
[key:any]: string
```

Once I removed this line, the typo was flagged again and Seal was suggested as corrective action.
Problem solved.